scrapy renew access token after some time
I am using scrapy to query an api with restricted access.
def start_requests(self):
    self.initialize_gcs_store()

    url = "https://api.example.com/authenticate"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    headers = {'authority': 'https://apply.workable.com'}
    payload = {
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
    }

    yield scrapy.Request(
        url=url,
        method='POST',
        meta={"task": ""},
        headers=headers,
        body=json.dumps(payload),
        errback=self.errback,
        callback=self.parse_access_token,
    )

def parse_access_token(self, response):
    
    access_token = json.loads(response.text)["jwt"]
    ...

the response from the authentication is an access token that is valid for 60 min. I would like to renew the access token after 60 min automatically. How could I do that with scrapy?

I suggest putting the access token in a redis or somewhere else so that your spider can focus on scraping the target site. It's hard to suspend the spider requests and renew the token first.
You can get it whenever your spider need the token from redis.
You can write a script to renew the token in the redis separately and run it every 60 min。

The main issue is that the scrapy requests are resolved and queued. So event if I check for token time validity, this does not work as the token is valid when the scraper starts. But after one hour, the some of the resolved requests are not.

@DJJ I mean: 1) Store the token at redis individually. 2) Run a script checking the time validity of the token every 60 min. Renew it if expired. 3) Get token from redis whenever a request started by scrapy.   By this way you can make sure your request is using the newest and valid token.
